# How to change post status from publish to draft using hook in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the status of already publish post to draft using its id.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status', 1 );
    function change_post_status( $post_id ){
        $my_post = array(
            'ID' => 1,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
        );
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('save_post', 'change_post_status');
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
        // re-hook this function
        add_action('save_post', 'change_post_status');
    }
```

I want to change the status of specific post which has id = 1 to be changed to draft.This is what I have tried and not got success . Neither I am getting any error, Can I do something to know if it is firing or not ? and how I can do it ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this.

Comment: @MHakvoort just posted there http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210752/how-to-change-post-status-from-publish-to-draft-using-hook-in-wordpress , I hope I will get some idea .